# Swift : How to implement Recording Bar Timer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avfoundation

Im trying to implement a recording progress bar similar to Vine and instagram. You'll typically see them at the very top of the screen, and when the user holds down(long press) the bar increases width. Then when the user lets go, it stops.

They also apply a function where you can delete the last scene of the video recorded(not important). So when the delete last scene button is selected, the area of the bar that was last recorded lights up a different color and if selected again will delete.

So basically my question is does anyone know of any tutorials that could help me with this? Anything on Github? Ive been looking everywhere but can't find anything. I have a basic understanding of how I'll do this, but theres some holes, so I want to see how others have implemented this Recording Bar.